# In a disconnected (N-tier) Entity Framework app, what is it that you bind to in the UI?

Tags: entity-framework

New to EF.

If I am using a disconnected approach, there wouldn't be a dbcontext.dbset.Local to bind (let's say for instance) a DataGrid. What am I supposed to do with the data that I pull into the context? Copy it to an ObservableCollection and then bind to a view of that? Then, attach the data back to a live dbcontext when it's time to savechanges?

Is it just wrong to keep the context open as long as I need to display the data, sort of like using it as an in memory database? Must the context really be created and then disposed of quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Copy it to an ObservableCollection and then bind to a view of that?**

Yes. Return the entities that will be used in the UI, not returning dbSet.Local, because it will not be able to be used when the context has been disposed.

**Then, attach the data back to a live dbcontext when it's time to savechanges?**

Yes.

> If you are working with disconnected objects you must manually manage
>   the synchronization. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee373856%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Is it just wrong to keep the context open as long as I need to display the data, sort of like using it as an in memory database? Must the context really be created and then disposed of quickly?**

It depends on what you're going to build. Here is a good tip:

> Most of them tend to point towards a short lived context that isn’t
>   shared.

More: [How to decide on a lifetime for your ObjectContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx)